# Large MATVEC broadcasting with numpy and performance

Tags: python, numpy, blas

I'm trying to implement this one-off data conversion of float64 data:

```
data_new[i,j,k,l,m,:,c] = matvec( data_orig[i,j,k,l,m,:,c], interp_matrix[:,:] )
```

where

```
"Shape data_orig:     (24,30,12,12,12,1024,2)   [20.4 GB]"
"Shape data_new:      (24,30,12,12,12,7776,2)   [154.8GB]"
"Shape interp_matrix: (1024,7776)"
```

My first approach has been running for about a day, still on the c=0 item.

```
data_new = np.zeros((24,30,12,12,12,7776,2))
for c in range(num_components):
    print("starting c=%d"%(c))
    data_new[...,c] = numpy.dot( data_orig[...,c],  interp_matrix )
```

Memory issues aside... (mostly.) I can move to a box with enough RAM at the moment.  I'll need to do something more robust for the future.

***How can I broadcast the operation over that highest "c" dimension?***

With that ability, I think I could try to loop over the leading dimension(s) instead, and hopefully enable threading.  `numpy.show_config()` tells me this Anaconda distribution of was built with mkl_intel_lp64 and mkl_intel_thread. I'm definitely using just one core on first approach.  Google searching leads me to think i'd need to set OMP_NUM_THREADS on a future attempt to enable threading.

Here's a more concise example:

```
>> np.dot( np.zeros((3,4,32,2))[...,:,0], np.zeros((32,128)) )
#works. :)

>> np.dot( np.zeros((3,4,32,2)), np.zeros((32,128)) )
ValueError: shapes (3,4,32,2) and (32,128) not aligned: 2 (dim 3) != 32 (dim 0)
```

Comment: The key thing with `dot` is the last dimension of `A` matches the 2nd to the last of `B`.  `np.tensordot` can cast the problem into that form by reshaping and transposing axes.  Your 1st loop work because `1024` matches.  In the 2nd case you have to, somehow, make `32` the last dimension of `A`.

Comment: It looks to me like  all you need is `interp_matrix.T @ data_orig`? (or `np.matmul(interp_matrix.T, data_orig)` on python 2)

Comment: On first checking of smaller problems, looks like you're right @Eric.
`numpy.matmul( np.zeros((32,128)).T, np.zeros((3,4,32,2)) )` and `data_new[...,c] = numpy.matmul( interp_matrix.T, data_orig )` work.

Comment: Performance looks to still be too slow to be useful on the real problem size.  I sample the process during the matmul call, and it looks to be doing a whole lot other than FMADDs. (i.e. `PyArray_EinsteinSum, PyArray_TransferNDimToStrided, _contig_to_contig, _platform_memmove, _aligned_strided_to_contig_size8, npyiter_copy_to_buffers, npyiter_buffered_reduce_iternext_iters3, PyArray_TransferStridedToNDim`
)  only 10% in `double_sum_of_products_two`.

Comment: I wasn't asking about performance though.  A `matmul` based answer with explanation of why it works (broadcasts) for the dimensions above and below the "matching" dimension would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In einstein summation notation, the product you're asking for is:

```
data_new[i,j,k,l,m,a,c] = data_orig[i,j,k,l,m,b,c] * interp_matrix[b,a]
```

Or in numpy:

```
data_new = np.einsum('ijklmbc,ba->ijklmac',data_orig, interp_matrix)
```

Reducing this step by step, with each equivalent to the last:

```
data_new = np.einsum('...bc,ba->...ac', data_orig, interp_matrix)
data_new = np.einsum('...bc,ab->...ac', data_orig, interp_matrix.T)
data_new = np.einsum('ab,...bc->...ac', interp_matrix.T, data_orig)
data_new = np.einsum('...ab,...bc->...ac', interp_matrix.T, data_orig)
                    # ^ This is the summation that matmul performs!
data_new = np.matmul(interp_matrix.T, data_orig)
data_new = interp_matrix.T @ data_orig
```